# drop down menu over a flash file

Tags: html, css, flash

I am using a drop down menu, with all its code written in .js file. 
I have a flash on my website. The drop down menu shows more content when you hover on top of any category, but this additional content is hiding behind the flash file, the flash file is over lapping the drop down menu content.

how can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the window mode (wmode) of your flash file to opaque. If you're dealing with absolute positioning, make sure the z-index it higher for your menu (probably already is if it's a pre-made dropdown).

Like:

swfobject:

```
swfobject.embedSWF("myContent.swf", "myContent", "300", "120", "9.0.0","expressInstall.swf", {}, {wmode: 'opaque'});
```

or

```
<param name="wmode" value="opaque">
```

in a typical definition.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Dan,

i actually found the solution and came back to answer my own question so that someone else can get the solution if they happened to face the same problem.

i just added "'wmode', 'transparent'" in the AC_FL_RunContent of the flash file and it worked just fine.

Thanks :)